# qTip and .Live() data

Tags: filtering, jquery, qtip

In Short,
I am currently showing a list of results... and then I place a filter on the results and pulls another list of results, using the .live() within jQuery.

Not my problem comes when i'm using qTip. Which currently runs somewhat like this... without all the details.

```
$('.contact').each(function() {
   $(this).qtip({
      // These are my options within here
   });
});
```

This if my code for filtering my results using the .live() feature.

```
$('.filterContacts').live('click', function(){
    var filterId = $(this).attr('id');  

    $.ajax({
    url: 'classes/class.Post.php?a=filterContacts',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        filter: filterId 
    },
    success: function (responseText) {
        $(".contacts").html(responseText);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Oops... Looks like we're having some difficulties.");  
    }
    });
    return false;
});
```

So now my qTip doesn't like to work on my filtered results... is there anything that I am able to do? Any help would be appreciative!

**UPDATE:**
.contacts is a div that surrounds all of the .contact divs.
*IE:*

```
<div class="contacts">
  <div class="contact">FistName, LastName</div>
  <div class="contact">FistName, LastName</div>
  <div class="contact">FistName, LastName</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @justin its contant there and contacts here is that fine.

Comment: do you have contact classes inside contacts

Comment: Hi Gov, I have updated my question in response to your comments...

Comment: @justin , when are you executing this code each(function()

Comment: you need to execute that in the success function so that the html will be ready by that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should execute your code in the success block.

```
$('.filterContacts').live('click', function(){
        var filterId = $(this).attr('id');  

        $.ajax({
        url: 'classes/class.Post.php?a=filterContacts',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            filter: filterId 
        },
        success: function (responseText) {
            $(".contacts").html(responseText);
            // call your each function here...
    $('.contact').each(function() {
       $(this).qtip({
          // These are my options within here
       });
    });


        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Oops... Looks like we're having some difficulties.");  
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: @justin , did you try the above.